# Insert a repetition of numbers in specific lines of a file

Tags: text-processing

[This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98582/insert-text-in-specific-lines-of-a-file) indicates how to insert text in specific lines of a file.

Instead of inserting text I would like to inseart a repetition of a number. 
For example this series:
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ... (100 times)

Comment: It might be better to edit your question to make it independent on other posts.  Do you want to insert a line formed of `2 2 2 ...`?  Where do you want to insert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the text you'd like inserted:

```
$ perl -e 'print "2 " x 99, "2\n"' >insert
```

Insert it into the file (on line 4 in this example):

```
$ cat file
The
Dog
Is
Here

$ sed '3r insert' file >file.tmp && mv file.tmp file

$ cat file
The
Dog
Is
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
Here
```

The `sed` editing command `r` ("read") will append the contents of a given file on the next line.

Comment: can be combined as single perl command... `perl -i -pe 'print "2 " x 99, "2\n" if $. == 4' file`.. or if extra space at end is not an issue, `perl -i -lpe 'print "2 " x 100 if $. == 4' file`