# How can I generate .out file within a shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, output

I wasn't sure how to word this question but basically I have been using a shell script to process sam data.
Here's the shell script.

```
nano picard_SortandIndex_from_sam.sh

for A in *sam; do ls $A; picard SortSam I=$A O=$A".bam" SO=coordinate CREATE_INDEX=TRUE; done
```

And this is the command I run where I get only one .out file for all the sam files processed.

```
nohup sh picard_SortandIndex_from_sam.sh > picard_SortandIndex_from_sam5_26_21.out &
```

Is there a way to generate .out files within my "picard_SortandIndex_from_sam.sh" script so I can have a summary file for each sam file processed? I tried to put > $A".out" in there but it didn't work...

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine the output of two commands in bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64736/combine-the-output-of-two-commands-in-bash)

Comment: If you want the `ls` output aswell, wrap the part between `do` and `done` like shown above, then redirect that ( `{ ls [...], picard [...] } >"$A".out`)

Comment: "I tried to put > $A".out" in there but it didn't work..." -- what does this mean, exactly? What did you try exactly? How did it not work? What happened instead?

Comment: @ilkkachu it actually worked but somehow the size of the new files didn't change until the whole step was finished. I thought it wasn't working. Turned out I just had to wait. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
for A in *sam; do 
  ls "$A"
  picard SortSam I="$A" O="$A".bam SO=coordinate CREATE_INDEX=TRUE > "$A".out
done
```

Or, more likely, you want both standard error and standard output, so use this:

```
for A in *sam; do 
  ls "$A"
  picard SortSam I="$A" O="$A".bam SO=coordinate CREATE_INDEX=TRUE > "$A".out 2>&1
done
```

This will run `picard` on each of your sam files, and store the output of the command (`> "$A".out`) *and* any errors produced (`2>&1`) in the file `$A.out`.

As a final note, since this creates files named `foo.sam.bam` and `foo.sam.bam.bai` etc., you might want to remove the `.sam` from the output name:

```
 for A in *sam; do 
  ls "$A"
  fileName=$(basename "$A" .sam)
  picard SortSam I="$A" O="$fileName".bam SO=coordinate CREATE_INDEX=TRUE > "$fileName".out 2>&1
done
```

That will create `foo.bam` from `foo.sam` instead of `foo.sam.bam`.

Comment: This worked!! Thank you so much!